# SQL QUERY list all users POSTGRESQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

---

```
SELECT  "cleaners".* FROM "cleaners"
INNER JOIN "cleaner_job_types" ON "cleaner_job_types"."cleaner_id" = "cleaners"."id" INNER JOIN "cleaner_working_hours" ON "cleaner_working_hours"."cleaner_id" = "cleaners"."id"
     LEFT JOIN client_hidden_cleaners ON client_hidden_cleaners.cleaner_id = cleaners.id
     WHERE ( cleaners.id IN (coalesce(1,2, 0))
                                 AND is_ok_with_pets = 't'
                                 AND cleaners.id NOT IN (coalesce(NULL, 0))
                                 AND job_type_id = 28)
                                 GROUP BY cleaners.id
```

I have some issue with listing all users which are in 
`cleaners.id IN (coalesce(1,2, 0))`
List only the first user id which is 1
Here is the output

> 1;1;"Fernando";"Gomez";"AX11D2";"2015-07-24 08:26:47.856344";"2015-08-03 11:54:51.905069";"Fernando's phone number";1;t

Comment: Do you know how coalesce works? It returns first non-null value which is 1 in your case. That's why your select lists only user with id=1.

Comment: Can you give me some alternative to return all values

Comment: If you want to return all users then remove your where condition. Why do you have any condition for cleaners.id when you want to list every cleaner?

Comment: I have where condition because cleaner can work for example from 10 to 12 or from 13:00 to 16:00.Also some cleaners can be banned from clients

Comment: Ok first of all read documentation of coalesce function. You do not understand that your where condition `WHERE ( cleaners.id IN (coalesce(1,2, 0))` returns cleaner which has id = 1. Remove this condition.

Comment: Yes i understand that thank you very much.Now i have to list all cleaners.And have to learn sql forsure :)

Comment: cleaners.id IN (?) works.Thank you again :)